# Dynamically create mysql tables per account or few large tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**What is a more optimized way of database designing?**

I am building an application where different companies register and add their users and use the application. I need up to 10 tables per account. e.g

`table1, table2, table3..table10`

This is what I am doing currently, having 10 tables and storing all the information from all accounts into these. But I just got an idea which is expands my database design horizontally. So the idea is whenever someone create an company account, my app would dynamically create these tables like the following:

`c_31_table1, c_31_table2, c_31_table3...c_31_table10`

Where `31` is the example accountid of the company which joined? My assumption is because SQL is only vertically increasing otherwise, it would get slow as time goes on, with around 40k records or more per table in the future. So this approach will keep the vertical lenght of the database down, and scale horizontally.

Is this technique a good optimization technique?

Comment: Multi-tenancy is the way to go. Refer this link -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1201dbdesigncloud/ for various ways to go about it

Comment: Thanks for the link Magesh, I have gone through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically not a great idea. Every situation is different. With this you would not benefit from query cache (as much). Your queries would require more work (not much) up front. And stored procs, funcs, and events would require `CONCAT`s, [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), `EXECUTE` and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.

Proper indexing and multi-tenancy should be your focus until you have a problem, which may be a long while off. I would focus here and with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) output as you develop. Profile your code. Always be profiling. Find out where routines are slow and fix them.

You will have a mumbo jumbo housekeeping mess with your proposed solution. They don't easily clean themselves up. Also, DDL calls are not cheap, even if on occasion.

If I worked at a place that suddenly wanted to name tables like

```
c_31_table1, c_31_table2, c_31_table3...c_31_table10
```

I would quit.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Also helping me find few new things about SQL. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider such approach as a case of "early optimization".

With just 40k rows the individual "companies do not pose any significant load by itself. You would "poison" your application code with the effects of your optimization even if the current load would not need it.

Maybe you will need to introduce some optimizations when the numer of companies grows (likely not before you are far beyond 1000 companies). Then you might e.g. consider partitioning as a means for reducing "vertical" length.

But keep your application clean from such optimizations. You would pay a high price throughout the life of your application otherwise.

Another aspect:

Allowing DDL calls will expose priviledges that you might not want to be exposed.